# Connection string for SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, connectivity

I am working with SQL Server. I used all connection via :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source = .; database = xyzDatabase; integrated security = true");//developed with developer edition.
```

Now I want to run my application on SQL Server Express, so I used this :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source = .\\sqlexpress; initial catalog = xyzDatabase; user id = sa; password = 123");
```

Point to remember is, I am creating my `xyzDatabase` at runtime on form load event. But when I execute the program I get this error :

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)*

Answer (score 0):

you must active sa user in sql express edition.

```
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("datasource=.\sqlexpress; initialcatalog=yzDatabase; userid=sa;password=123");
```

Comment: Don't **EVER** use the `sa` account - **N-E-V-E-R** !! Either use integrated security, or use **explicit** users for your application.

Comment: with mssql ide, you can login and change security of sqlexpress.

Answer (score 0):

Import the namespaces

using System.Data.SqlClient (if using C#)
or
Imports System.Data.SqlClient (if using VB#)

Your Sql connection object with connection would be like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Database=xyzDatabase;User Id=sa;Password=admin@123;");
```

If still your error not resolved, it might be the problem of incorrect installation of MS-SQL SERVER instances.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Hope it might be helpful.